# Unable to hide a column in "NewForm" using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

Last week i was able to hide 2 site columns from New list form using this PnP script (the fields were of type Single line of text and Date/Time):-

```
$User = "admin@****.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteURL = "https://****.sharepoint.com"
#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "enterpassword" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$fieldTitle = "ProjectNumber"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$customfield.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but today when i try the above script to hide a site column of type drop-down on the same site collection>> i got this error on the $Context.ExecuteQuery(), as follow-

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $Context.ExecuteQuery()
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

now i do not think the issue is with the field type, as i usually hide drop-down column using this PnP script without any issue.. but not sure what is going on, as this script was working for me last week (4-5 days ago!!).

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the PowerShell script as below.

```
$fieldTitle = "ProjectNumber"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$customfield.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: this worked for me,, but not sure what is the differences between the 2 approaches ? and why my appraoch use to work well for me...

Comment: Check the article here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/sharepoint-csom-and-the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context/